# CKEditor - Editor gets disabled and Text cleared on display of Modal dialog

Tags: ckeditor, editor

we use CK editor for editing purpose in a form. We also have a hidden div instance in the page, which keeps a timer. This is for displaying a warning on session timeout. When this dialog is displayed to show warning message, the background editor (ckeditor) gets disabled and text is cleared.

Not sure where to get the resolution process started. Any tips would be highly appreciated. I also downloaded the latest version of ckeditor and still has the same issue.

Thanks,

John

Comment: Further analysing through dev tool realized that the content is captured inside ckeditor in an iframe and HTML inside iframe.  the P tag that holds the content typed in by user is cleared when the modal dialog is displayed.  Is this because of the usage of iframe by ckeditor ?? any resolutions ???

Comment: if we open the modal dialogs defined by the ckeditor, the content typed in by user stays in the text area. For ex. The paste, attachments icons when clicked will open a dialog, and in this case the typed in content stays. Also when a model dialog defined in hte page outside ckedit opens as part of a user click, then also the content stays. However when a modal dialog defined in the parent page opens without user interaction (automatically) as in the timer window, then the content typed in by user is cleared and the ckeditor goes in to a freeze mode.

Comment: one more important update , the ck editor window itself is a modal dialog.